# Is there a way to view compiler generated code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a way to view C++ compiler generated code in Visual Studio? What I mean by generated code is: compiler generated functions, function call transformations, casts during polymorphic behavior etc. and not assembly language

Comment: When you say *C++ compiler generated* are you talking about after the preprocessor runs, or are you looking to see things like the special member functions it creates for classes if you don't implement them?

Comment: Do you want the preprocessed code, compiler-generated  member functions, assembly, ...? Please be more specific. There are very many steps to compilation

Comment: I want compiler generated code like generated functions, function call transformations, casts during polymorphic behaviour etc.. no assembly

Comment: Are you wondering how that compiler can be so bugged and crappy? :D

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: The compiler only generates those things in assembly. There's no other language with which to view them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the generated assembly code (and/or machine code), you can select this in the properties, either per-project or per-source file. Various levels of detail are available.

Right click the project or source file in the Solution Explorer, select the "Properties" command and then, in the "C/C++" tab, select which type (if any) of assembler output you want:

[image]

If you select any type of output, a file (or files) with the source(s) name(s) and the ".asm" extension will be generated in the project's "Intermediate" directory (where the ".obj" files are placed) by default, but this folder can be changed using the "ASM List Location" property.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by 'generated code' you will sometimes see files in the build directories (x64\Debug for example), for example the #using directive will generate .tlh and .tli files that then get incorporated into the build.

(From a comment) I had not been aware of this but it is also possible to have MSVC directly output generated assembly using the /Fa compiler option.

Comment: VC++ can output assembly just like gcc does. See [`/Fa`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-160#fa-argument) flag.